# Phaser 3 images in dev folder?

Tags: javascript, typescript, phaser-framework

I'm following a very basic Phaser 3 example, but the problem is that the `dist` folder only contains a bundle.js file, and all assets are still loaded from the `src` folder.

Folder structure:

```
dist
  - bundle.js
src
  assets
    - bmo.png
  scenes
    - game-scene.ts
```

Loading code:

```
  export class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene {

  constructor() {
    super({key: "GameScene"});
  }

  preload(): void {
    this.load.image('bmo', './src/assets/bmo.png');
  }
}
```

But now the image is loaded from the `src` folder! This isn't right is it? 
How do I export the game including a html file and asset files?

Currently I run webpack using `npm run dev` to test the game.

Comment: That's the relative path from your TypeScript file but there's probably a compilation step for you to serve the site from a folder like `public` or `dist`. Make sure you can reach the assets from the serving location if you're not bundling your assets to that directory via `webpack` etc.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question. The image is now found, but it seems weird to me that the game references the `src` folder to find the image.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `file-loader` for Webpack.

`$ npm install file-loader --save-dev`

Add the file-loader setting your webpack config like:

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {},
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Then, you can import the file in your TypeScript file like:

`import img from './src/assets/bmo.png';`

If you feel confused with the setting options in Webpack, there are plenty of examples in the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/).

Comment: Thanks, the confusion came from using an example project, but apparently that wasn't meant to actually export a game.

Comment: Probably not if it's a basic demo. I know it's not TS but [this boilerplate](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser3-project-template) has file loading setup already. If you check their Webpack settings, you can see how it's exactly setup.

Comment: Sorry but it's not yet working. When I `import` the image, I now get `cannot find module './src/assets/bmo.png'`. I have tried all kinds of variations of the path. My path autocomplete says that the path is correct. `file-loader` does not copy any images either.

Comment: And another question, why is the `html` file in the root? Shouldn't that be in `dist` too? I've looked at the boilerplate but that's completely different...